# Setting dateFormat on jQuery UI datepicker, on a non-empty field

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need my dateformat to be in `dd/mm/yyyy`
and therefore need to use this following code:

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

But, when using just this line, I don't get the datepicker popup calendar.

If I use this, i get the popup, but then I lose the pre-set date in the value of the field

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker();
$(".date-pick").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
```

See here - https://jsfiddle.net/kneidels/hkbgzvmt/

What code can I use to (1) have the `dd/mm/yyyy` format,  as well as (2) have the pre-set date value shown?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended way is to define the [defaultDate](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) and [dateFormat](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat) when instantiating the datepicker: https://jsfiddle.net/tg7yv149/1/

```js
$(function() {
  $(".date-pick").datepicker({
    defaultDate: $(this).val(),
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
  });
});
```

Another way that works is to store the value in a variable, instantiate the datepicker, then apply the value again: https://jsfiddle.net/Lyneb7j9/

```js
$(function() {
    var myval = $(".date-pick").val();
  
    $(".date-pick").datepicker();
    $(".date-pick").datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd/mm/yy");
    $(".date-pick").val(myval);
});
```

Comment: This works well, thanks. But shouldn't the script be able work properly straight from 'the box', so to speak? I suspect I have something wrong in the formatting. Question is what?

Comment: @kneidels I've updated the answer to show how to do that.